# Include a file in a CocoaPod that is external from the project

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a situation where I have created a CocoaPod for internal use that relies on an external file that must be shared among several projects.

The folder structure looks something like this

```
- Home
-- Libraries
--- iOS
--- Android
-- Shared Components
--- Shared Headers
---- Header
--- Source
```

What I need is to have a Pod located in the \Home\Libraries\iOS folder access files under Shared Components.

Everything from \Home on down is stored in source control, so it will be available.

I have attempted to modify the source_files value in my Podspec file to point to `..\..\SharedComponents\SharedHeaders\Header\**\* & ..\..\SharedComponents\Source\**\*`, but that has not worked.

Comment: i guess podfile will be available in source control. but what happened is you added that file in Home. it will be out of your project IOS. Try to add that pod file inside your project then the problem will be solved.

Comment: I wish I could have, but that file could not move because of other dependencies. I was able to solve it with the solution I marked below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I could resolve the issue by creating sym links in the iOS folder that pointed to the files in the ....\SharedComponents\SharedHeaders\Header*** & ....\SharedComponents\Source*** folders.

Then, I imported the sym link files into Xcode, and was able to successfully use the files in the CocoaPod.

For anyone who is not familiar with the syntax to create symlinks, it looked like this:

```
ln -s ../../SharedComponents/SharedHeaders/Header/SomeFile.h .
ln -s ../../SharedComponents/Source/SomeFile.cpp .
```

ln [link] -s [symlink] ../path/to/file [original file] /new/file/path (or . for current) [new location]